# Sort dataframe by value returns "For a multi-index, the label must be a tuple with elements corresponding to each level."

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Objective: Based off dataframe with 5 columns, return dataframe with 3 columns including one which is the count and sort by largest count to smallest.

What I have tried:

```
df = df[['Country', 'Year','NumInstances']].groupby(['Country', 'Year']).agg(['count'])

df = df.sort_values(by='NumInstances', ascending=False)

print(df)
```

Error:
ValueError: The column label 'NumInstances' is not unique.
For a multi-index, the label must be a tuple with elements corresponding to each level.

Before this gets mark as a duplicate, I have gone through all other suggested duplicates and it seems they all suggest using the same code as I have above.

Is there something small that I am doing that may be incorrect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. Adding an agg to the NumInstances column made the NumInstances column name a tuple of ('NumInstances', 'sum'), therefore I just updated the sort code to:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=('NumInstances', 'sum'), ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to remove multi-index -

Try this -

```
df = df[['Country', 'Year','NumInstances']].groupby(['Country', 'Year']).agg(['count']).reset_index()
```

or -

```
df = df[['Country', 'Year','NumInstances']].groupby(['Country', 'Year'], as_index=False).agg(['count'])
```

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to be ordering by country name only